# Null result for date object fetched from DB giving sysDate/current date on mapping to Java object

Tags: java, database, oracle, date, orm

I fetched data from the oracle database through java code using a query similar to the below:

select min(specDate) from table

The result is supposed to be of type Date.

Since there was no specDate populated for any of the rows in the table, the result was `null`.

I used this query in my java code and mapped it to Date object using BeanPropertyRowMapper.

The result I got after mapping was the system date or the current date.

Not sure as to why the mapper returned current date instead of null.

Comment: Ok. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why did null become sysDate after mapping?

Comment: Are you using any ORM? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.

When the BeanPropertyRowMapper was provided with Date.class for mapping,
new Date() is called for instantiation of the class like for any object.

But for Date.class, new Date() returns sysDate.